# How do I connect a vm to my opt1 network of pf sense

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, pfsense

My pfsense is setup with 3 network adapters:

- Adapter 1 being 'NAT'
- Adapter 2 being 'Internal Network' and is on Lan1
- the third Adapter is 'Host-Only adapter' and is on 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3'

My pfsense has the Wan Lan and Opt1 all setup with different IP addresses.

**I need to have my Kali VM connected to the Lan network and my Ubuntu VM connected to the Opt1 network.**

If anyone can tell me how to put Ubuntu onto the `Opt1` network that would be great, I've tried searching and changing adapters and using the same network as Kali but I can't figure out how to put my Ubuntu onto `Opt1`. I can provide screenshots of everything, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the Kali VM network adapter to be on "Internal Network" with the *same name* as the pfSense adapter #2.

For the Ubuntu VM:

- If you *need* the "Host-Only" adapter for some other purpose:

  Configure the Ubuntu VM network adapter to be in "Bridged" mode and attach it to the Host-Only adapter that exists on the host.
- If you *don't* need the "Host-Only" adapter and only need Opt1↔Ubuntu:

  Configure both the pfSense VM adapter #3 and the Ubuntu VM adapter to be on "Internal Network" with a *different* name than the one used by adapter #2 – but still identical between both Opt1 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, the second option worked. My new problem is I have setup a vsftpd server and I have firewalld configured to have tcp ports 20,21,22 and when I do nmap scan on kali it says that the host is down but when I probe it it says all 1000 tcp ports are in ignored states how do I get the nmap on kali to pick up the ports and connect to the vsftpd server